# Parsing json in underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following json and i need to display the value of "sf"..

```
 {
    "ss": 1,
    "me": "Successfully Retrieved",
    "pp": {
        "uid": 18,
        "ut": "T",
        "fn": "Dark",
        "te": {
            "sf": "asd"
        }
    }
 }
```

I have passed the data to html page as data and i can get the following values :

```
data.pp.uid
```

But im not able to get the value of :

```
data.pp.te.sf
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm getting it just fine. Can you provide a fiddle

Comment: Sounds like it's being parsed incorrectly. How exactly is it being parsed? Do you receive an error when trying to access `data.pp.te.sf`?

Comment: 1. where is the underscore here ?  2. it works for others , show more code.

Comment: typo error... i removed the "pp" node while testing... now it works fine.. i tested it separately after removing from the file and it worked.. 

data.pp.te.sf

Thanks Guys,,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works fine for me in Chrome:

```
var test  = {
    "ss": 1,
    "me": "Successfully Retrieved",
    "pp": {
        "uid": 18,
        "ut": "T",
        "fn": "Dark",
        "te": {
            "sf": "asd"
        }
    }
 }
test.pp.te.sf 

"asd"
```

Comment: That is clearly not an answer.

Comment: typo error... i removed the "pp" node while testing... now it works fine.. i tested it separately after removing from the file and it worked.. 

data.pp.te.sf

Thanks Andre..

Comment: It's always the little things hehe! 
Glad it worked out for you.